# how to pass params using a route in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, routes, parameters

i have a router `test/view` and i would like to pass some params like `test/view/id/123`.

Im not sure how to add those params in the zf2 router.

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'test' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/test',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'test\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'view' => array(
                        'type' => 'Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/view',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Index',
                                'action'     => 'view',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
),
```

i setup `view` as a child route but not sure where to add those params.

i've tried `'route' => '/view/:id/:value'` and

```
'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Index',
    'action'     => 'view',
    'id'         => 'value',
)
```

but they don't seem to work

i am trying to understand how all this works.

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'test-view' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/test/view/:testId[/]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'testId'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Test\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'view'
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

In your ControllerAction you can then get the parameter "testId" by using:

```
$this->params('testId');
```

Btw: The above route gives you an url like this: `/test/view/123` - I thought you may get rid of the "id" param.

If you want to create a link to one kind of this pages, you can use `$this->url('test-view', array('testId' => 123))` in one of your views.

Comment: Do you use the skeleton app? You need a "Test" Module. Wait, i will put one up for you.

Comment: i have a test module, the view action, and the module.config, yes

Comment: i've figure it out. thanks  more here : http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html

Comment: What was it? Did you forget to put "Test" to the modules array in application.config.php?

Comment: i did this `/view[/:id]` and my link is `/test/view/123`. if i want `/test/view/id/123` i will have to have a route for `/view/id[/:id]`

Comment: Sure, but in your case "id" is optional because of the brackets. Keep that in mind. I would suggest /test/view/id/:id[/] - but also you could skip the "/id/" part as it just makes your url more user-unfriendly, don't you think?