# How to pass parameters by url with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm getting into trouble with passing param by url in Zend Framework 2. For example : I want to access page by a URL like this: 
http://example.com/student/details/aaa it's working, but if my url like this :
http://example.com/student/details/1 it's not working,  And  i still get a 404.

I tried to follow the instruction from [how to pass params using a route in Zend Framework 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353770/how-to-pass-params-using-a-route-in-zend-framework-2)

But it still doesn't work.

here's my module.config.php

```
'student' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/student[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'AppFeeder\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Student',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

And i use this `$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id')` in my controller.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong route rule for id which says start from alphabet then alphabet+number+"_-".

```
 'id'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
```

Instead you need to change the rule that says start from alphabet+number then alphabet+number+"_-"

```
 'id'     => '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
```

Comment: Do you have any clue how to pass two variables in url zend?